# Drupal module CSS character adjustment

Tags: css, drupal, character, drupal-modules, vote-up-buttons

I built Bachelor10.com with some assistance a few years back. I used the Vote Up/Down module.
On pages like this, http://bachelor10.com/bachelor-handbook/top-10-bachelor-party-movies, the Vote Up/Down module is in triple digits on both positive and negative and is forcing wonky CSS issues.
I'd prefer to avoid resetting all the counters, so could someone show me how to adjust the CSS in Drupal to allow for the character limits?

Answer (score 0):

In style.css, line 603 there is `div.vud-widget`.
Change the width to 200 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution but more future proof, set the width to auto.

```
div.vud-widget {
    width: auto;
}
```